# Python; screen exit error

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

1. I have made a code in two files in python.
2. From main.py a function screen is called which have some radio button.
3. error is when I run the code & main screen is opened, if click "Ok"
   button then it work fine. However if I close the window by pressing close button, error appears.

   ```
   [code]

   Exception in Tkinter callback
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
       return self.func(*args)
   File "E:\main_menu.py", line 51, in suicide
       self.screen.destroy()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1898, in __getattr__
       return getattr(self.tk, attr)
   AttributeError: screen
   [/code]
   ```
4. main.py
       [code]

   ```
   import main_menu

   while True:
       val = main_menu.screen()
       if(1 == val):
           //do something
       elif(2 == val):
           //do something
       elif(3 == val):
           //do something

       #print(val)    
   [/code]
   ```
5. main_screen.py
       [code]

   ```
   from Tkinter import *
   import Tkinter



   class menu1(Tkinter.Tk):

       def __init__(self, master):
           Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,master)
           self.master = master

           self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.suicide)

           #clear value
           self.val1 = 1

           #default selection
           self.v = IntVar()
           self.v.set(1)

           #create a label
           self.x1 = Label(self,text="Choose a function:",justify = CENTER,padx = 100)
           self.x1.pack()

           #first radiobutton
           self.x2 = Radiobutton(self,text="text1",padx = 100,variable=self.v,value=1)
           self.x2.pack(anchor=W)

           #second radiobutton
           self.x3 = Radiobutton(self,text="text2",padx = 100,variable=self.v,value=2)      
           self.x3.pack(anchor=W)

           #third radiobutton
           self.x4 = Radiobutton(self,text="text3",padx = 100,variable=self.v,value=3)    
           self.x4.pack(anchor=W)

           #fourth radiobutton
           self.x5 = Radiobutton(self,text="text4",padx = 100,variable=self.v,value=4)    
           self.x5.pack(anchor=W)

           #create button
           self.x6 = Button(self,text="OK",command=self.submit)    
           self.x6.pack()

       def submit(self):
           self.val1 = self.v.get()
           self.destroy()

       def suicide(self):
           self.val1  = 0
           self.screen.destroy()        

   def screen():
       #create a root object
       root = menu1(None)
       root.title("Option")
       root.geometry("480x320")
       root.mainloop()
       return root.val1      
   [/code]
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.screen.destroy()` raises an exception because you do not have a `self.screen`.

I think you just need `self.destroy()`, as in the `submit()` method above